# Protect nextjs API route even with guest users?

Tags: next.js

I have guest users that still need to be able to write into the database.  The only thing I want to prevent are users you go to the URL/use postman to do: [www.website.com/api/route/random-type](http://www.website.com/api/route/random-type). To make a get request.

I've tried blocking it by checking if the cookies and the URL match, but sadly, the URL/route/query is not available on first load (undefined).

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method } = req;
  const userId = req.query.id; //undefined
  const userCookieId = req.cookies?.uid || req.cookies?.guestId;
  const authUser = userId === userCookieId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method } = req;
  const userId = req.query.id;
  const userCookieId = req.cookies?.uid || req.cookies?.guestId;
  
  if (method === 'GET' && userId !== userCookieId) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
}
```